# How can I import a resource folder in my component to avoid the "../../../resources/images/.." path?

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that use some static resources. How can I import this **resources** folder in order to avoid a long path for img src like in this example:

```
<img src={require('../../../resources/images/anony.png')}/>
```

(The project has been created with "*npm create-react-app*" and the **resources** folder is located inside the **src**)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your webpack config to add [additional resolve paths](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/). If you add the resources parent folder as a root path (or alias it) you could `import ‘resources/images/anony.png’`.